# Python Pandas remove .0 from data in column without losing trailing zeros

Tags: python

Having an issue when I remove '.0' that it is also removing the trailing zeros. I have the following dataframe:

```
Product Number Materia      Key
100000080      100000080.0  CUIP717610000008
```

I tried:

```
df['Material'] = df['Product Number'].astype(str)
df['Key'] = df['Target Location'] + df['Material'].str.rstrip(r'\.0')
```

Ideally, I would like Material reflected as an object without the '.0' before the concatenate, but this is what I have been able to get so far.  The key is dropping the .0 and the last zero.

Comment: I removed your `PANDAS` tag, because this problem has nothing to do with the data frame.  Please supply the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) when you post.  The problem is that you specifically told it to remove all trailing zero and dot characters.  Read the `rstrip` documentation.

Comment: Why are you doing number things with strings? Do number things with numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split by '.' and get the first string:

```
df['Material'] = df['Product Number'].astype(str)
df['Key'] = df['Target Location'] + df['Material'].str.split('.').str[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

`rstrip` documentation is clear on this: it removes all listed characters from the right side of the string.  You specified two characters, zero and dot -- the function will keep taking all of those characters from the right side until it hits something not in that set.  Instead, you need to filter out a two-character string at the end.

Write a filter for `endswith(".0")`, or perhaps `s[-2:] == ".0"`.  Return the whole string if it fails, but s[:-2] when you get a match.